# PHP, mySql Select all with the same name

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a table where some of the products repeat with but have a different value on number of clicks.

```
name ----  clicks
iPhone       4
Samsung      2
iPhone       1
Samsung      5
```

my select function is :

```
$select_table2 = 'SELECT * FROM `mytable`'; //WHERE NAME IS THE SAME
$sql2 = $db->query($select_table2);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)) {
 echo $row["name"];
 echo $row["clicks"];
}
```

I need this output:

```
iPhone       5
Samsung      7
```

I don't want to merge the same rows because they have one more column that is different. So please do not suggest simply to merge them and update the clicks...

UPDATE:

```
$pull_request = 'SELECT SUM(e.product_clicks),e.product_id, u.name, u.product_id FROM `oc_aa_affiliatecollclicktracking` AS e GROUP BY e.product_id  LEFT JOIN  `'.DB_PREFIX.'product_description` AS u ON e.product_id = u.product_id';
```

I tried it like this but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `sum()` and also `GROUP BY name` to get desired output.

```
$select_table2 = 'SELECT name,SUM(clicks) FROM `mytable` GROUP BY name'; 
$sql2 = $db->query($select_table2);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)) {
  echo $row["name"];
  echo $row["clicks"];
}
```

while will produce,

```
iPhone       5
Samsung      7
```

For more info

- [SUM()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)
- [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html)

**EDIT**

Group by should come after join.

```
$pull_request = 'SELECT SUM(e.product_clicks) as clicks,e.product_id, u.name, u.product_id FROM `oc_aa_affiliatecollclicktracking` AS e   
LEFT JOIN  `'.DB_PREFIX.'product_description` AS u ON e.product_id = u.product_id
GROUP BY e.product_id';
```

Comment: SELECT SUM(e.product_clicks),e.product_id, u.name, u.product_id FROM `oc_aa_affiliatecollclicktracking` AS e GROUP BY e.product_id  LEFT JOIN  `'.DB_PREFIX.'product_description` AS u ON e.product_id = u.product_id

Comment: add database design as well.

Comment: @Grasper I have edited my answer, please check that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92755/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-grasper).

Answer (score 1):

You want to perform a SUM command by group

```
$query = "SELECT `name`,SUM(`clicks`) FROM `mytable` GROUP BY `name`";
```

Edit: The other answer was more complete than mine.  I forgot to select `name` field. Added.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an aggregate function for suming the clicks [SUM(clicks)], and a Group By clause for defining the classification criteria [GROUP BY name].

The other answers where wrong in the sense that are assuming that by changing the select field list adding the aggregate 'SUM', the associative references (eg: index strings of the $row array ) remains the same, the correct query would be:

```
$select_table2 = 'SELECT name, SUM (clicks) AS clicks FROM mytable GROUP BY name';
```

Note the alias on SUM(clicks) AS clicks, so the fields returned in the array $row keep their indexes (clicks, names... instead of 'SUM(clicks)')

And the rest is basically the same.

Cheers!

Comment: The Alias, the alias, I told ya!, Good everything worked.

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
$select_table2 = 'SELECT name, SUM (clicks) FROM mytable GROUP BY name';
```